# What options do Anglican clergy have if they run out of holy oil to anoint the sick?

Tags: anglicanism, anointing-of-the-sick

Church of England clergy obtain holy oils to anoint the sick - or those receiving the sacraments of the church - at the annual service at their cathedral, the [Chrism Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrism_Mass).

This has become harder to access during the COVID-19 pandemic. What options do clergy have if they run out of holy oil to anoint the sick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canon B 37 'Of the ministry to the sick' [states](https://www.churchofengland.org/about/leadership-and-governance/legal-services/canons-church-england/section-b):

> 3. If any such person so desires, the priest may lay hands upon him and may anoint him with oil on the forehead with the sign of the Cross using a form of service authorized by Canon B 1 and using **pure olive oil consecrated by the bishop of the diocese or otherwise by the priest himself in accordance with such form of service.**

*Common Worship* includes a [Short Form of Prayer Over The Oil](https://www.churchofengland.org/prayer-and-worship/worship-texts-and-resources/common-worship/wholeness-and-healing/wholeness-and), which the priest may use to consecrate such oil:

> Lord, holy Father, giver of health and salvation, as your apostles anointed those who were sick and healed them, so continue the ministry of healing in your Church. Sanctify this oil, that those who are anointed with it may be freed from suffering and distress, find inward peace, and know the joy of your salvation, through your Son, our Saviour Jesus Christ. Amen.